# Move a Point on Delphi

Tags: delphi, grid, delphi-xe8

I'm using MapWinGis to plot my .shp on delphi

```
var shp: Shapefile;
 HandleLayer: integer;
begin
  shp:= CoShapefile.Create;
  shp.Open ('C:\Users\Suporte\Desktop\opa\Win32\Debug\Amostragem.shp', nil) ;
  Map1.Focused;
  HandleLayer:= Map1.AddLayer (shp, true);
  Map1.ZoomToMaxExtents;
end;
```

its possible to move this points?
o i have to build this points on delphi to move ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by moving the points?

Comment: on other gis software i can click,hold and just move the point wherever i want

Comment: So are you looking for how to click/drag plotted points, or for how to modify the points in the file, or both?

Comment: both eventually, its basic drag and drop